# Flex: empty window on HelloWorld app

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm totally new to flex and tried to create `helloWorld` app unsuccessfully.
Steps:

1) Create flex project within flash builder;
2) Added `<s:Label text="Hello World" x="100" y="100" />` to `HelloWorld.mxml` file in default package;
3) runned project with Flash Builder;
4) saw an empty flash page in browser window;

Did I miss something?

`HelloWorld.mxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Label text="Hello World" x="100" y="100" />
</s:Application>
```

P.S.
- Flash Builder 4.6;
- SDK 4.5.1;
- Other flash page do work correctly in browser (Chrome);

Comment: Do you mean that you used Flash Builder 4.6?  Is "Build Automatically" selected from the project menu?   If not; you may have to manually build the project after adding the label.  You can do this from the project menu using "Build All".  You may also try "Clean" from the project menu.  I see no reason why this code wouldn't work.

Comment: @www-flextras-com, yes, 4.6; 
 "Build Automatically" is selected;

Comment: do you see your label in edition mode ? are you sure you see a flash empty page or just a html page ? (right click -> flash parameters)

Comment: @www-flextras-com, yes, 4.6; 
"Build Automatically" is selected;
tried "Clean" from the project menu, still the same output -- empty page;

Comment: @Majid LAISSI, sure, i see my label in "design" mode; 
hmm... after clicking on `Run [project name]` -> `[project_name]/bin-debug/HelloWord.html` is opened. On the right mouse click i got the "standart" flash context menu.

Comment: try to clear your browser's cache.. may be it still "remembers" an older version of your `HellowWorld.swf`.

Comment: @Majid LAISSI, Done; didn't help.

Comment: delete your swf in big-debug, try to rebuild and make sure it's recreated. Then try and open directly the swf in your browser.

Comment: @Majid LAISSI, i can see my object when i directly open the swf object from bin-debug folder but i dont this that label when trying to open project in a browser. (P.S. deleted the swf and generated a new one)

Comment: 1)did you try to open this swf in different browser? 2)Make sure to clear browser cache when your swf is not opened anywhere, and you can try to delete files manually.3)Sometimes it's easy to forget to save edited file, this isn't your case, is it? 4)Reliable approach to see if your swf is updated or not is to Alert.show('version') or to draw big red line across your app with graphics.

Comment: I would try to select another browser (if you have any others) in menu  Window-Preferences-General-Browser. I suppose it's a problem with it. The code is no doubt correct.

Comment: @ted well if you see your label in the swf directly, but not in your browser, then you definitely have a problem in your html. Check its source code to see whether it references your swf correctly

Comment: Definitely try another browser!! Make sure that stupid Pepper Flash that chrome uses is not causing the problem. It's quite buggy and seems to cause a lot of random issues. You can disable it by going to chrome://plugins

Comment: hmm... everything works great in `FireFox`. Thank you. Would any one post an answer so i can accept it? @user1875642 was the first (:

Comment: @SunilD., sorry, hadn't found any "Pepper Flash" in chrome plugins

Comment: Double check, Pepper Flash is the default Flash plugin in Chrome. Clicks the plus icon (details) in the plugins list. You likely have several Flash plugins installed. Look for the one that has "PepperFlash" in the path. I've seen the exact behavior you describe caused by Pepper Flash :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, reposted from comment.

1. Did you try to open this swf in different browser?
2. Make sure to clear browser cache when your swf is not opened anywhere, and you
   can try to delete files manually.
3. Sometimes it's easy to forget to save edited file, this isn't your case, is it?
4. Reliable approach to
   see if your swf is updated or not is to Alert.show('version') or to
   draw big red line across your app with graphics.

Comment: p.s. just for someone issueing the same problem: 1 -- helped; Was trying in Chrome, everything worked well in Firefox;